# Sql Server Cloud Adapter Missing while deploying in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, sitecore, cloud

I am trying to install Sitecore (CMS) in Azure. As a part of the process, i am trying to install Sql and i am facing the following issues. 
I have a VM where i have SQL server 2014  installed.
Whenever i try to install Sitecore on Azure with SQL in my VM, i get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum,
>   Version=11.0.0.0,

```
Initializing database deployment failed ---> System.ApplicationException: Initializing database deployment is failed ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.DeployDatabasePipelineArgs..ctor(DatabaseReference databasesDefinition)
```

I tried checking for this DLL in GAC folder and was not able to find this. i am quite not sure where to start with. Google is not much help. 
Any direction on how to proceed this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly is a part of Microsoft Shared Management Objects.
Installation of SMO is a part of pre-requirements for [Sitecore Azure installation](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/azure/310/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_310-a4.pdf).

> Download and install [these tools](http://www.microsoft.com/enus/download/details.aspx?id=38797) from Microsoft:
>
> - Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Shared Management Objects
> - Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012
>
> Sitecore Azure requires that you install these tools on your local — on premises — content editing environment (Web Server).
>
> Download and install [these tools](http://www.microsoft.com/enus/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065) from Microsoft — :
>
> - SQLSysClrTypes.msi (X64 Package)
> - Shared Management Objects.msi (X64 Package)

**Update:**

Links are outdated. The tools can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065)

Comment: The links above are invalid, pretty sure it's just a typo, the first and second links in order are:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38797

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065